# Private variables and access to parent object

Tags: javascript, closures, this, private

I want a main object M containing a sub-object S which has some method E which has a private variable P. I also want the method E to have access to M via another variable V. For the private variables I'm doing this:

```
M.S = function () {
    var P,
        V; // how to set V to M?

    return {
        E: function () {
            // stuff goes here
        }
    }
}();
```

One solution I came up with was to remove the () at the last line, and then calling the anonymous S-creating function as a method of M. this solves the problem, but I'm thinking there might be a more elegant way to go about it.

```
M.S = function () {
    var P,
        V = this;

    return {
        E: function () {
            // stuff goes here
        }
    }
};
M.S = M.S()
```

Mostly I need to know what is good practice for this, since I'm new to private variables in Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pretty straightforward method to do this is:

```
M.S = function (V) { // <-- V is declared locally
    var P;

    return {
        E: function () {
            // stuff goes here
        }
    };
}(M);
```

`V` is locally declared through the formal parameter. `M`'s reference is assigned to `V`, through `function(V){...}(M);`.

Even when `M` is redeclared at a later point, `V` will still point to the right object.

Comment: This is beautifully simple! What I was originally looking for was a way to do it using "this", but this saves me a line of code. :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this? You invoke `S` in context of `M`:

```
M.S = function () {
    var P,
        V = this; // how to set V to M?

    return {
        E: function () {
            // stuff goes here
            // you can refer M via V reference
        }
    }
}.call(M);
```

Comment: Great solution, and it showed me how to solve the problem I was trying to solve: calling the function that creates S from the context of M. Thank you!